# Magento 2 : Coupon Code for Child of Configurable Product

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, coupon, coupon-codes

I have configurable product. It has sizes of bottles like 4oz, 16oz, 32oz, Gallon. I want to apply coupon code that works on 16oz.

I add 16 oz bottle to my cart, and if I just apply coupon to items in that category then it will work, but it will do it also for 32oz bottles. If I add condition to be "Bottle Size" (configured attribute) is equal to "16 oz". Then coupon just always fails.

The only error on cart is:

```
The coupon code "testcoupon" is not valid.
```

I assume, it's not able to recognize simple item  which is selected that matches 16 oz attribute, configurable item doesn't have the attribute and even if it's selected in cart it's not recognized by coupon system.

Most items I have with attributes are set that way for configurable items, but I have just a couple that are set and there is no configuration. For these coupon seems to work because attribute is defined. But unless this works for configurable items it makes configurable items kind of unusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue by just setting the coupon to work based on the SKU of the item. So we just add a SKU list to the coupon instead of trying to attach to the attribute. I would think either option would work, but as long as one of the methods works it's acceptable for now.